# add_sorted function in linked lists

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am currently trying to make a linked list with a function that can add integers sorted to the list while using some of the functions I made, but I am running into a problem with my code:

```
void list::add_sorted(int el)
    {
      if (empty()) add_first(el);
      else if (el<=head->data) add_first(el);
      else if (el >= tail->data) add_last(el);
    }
```

And I am wondering why the output in my code:
3

While in the main function i wrote :

```
list t1;
t1.add_sorted(5);
t1.add_sorted(3);
t1.add_sorted(9);
t1.print();
```

Here is the implementation for add_first(int el) , add_last(int el) and  empty():

```
list::list()
{
  head = tail = 0;

}
bool list::empty()
{
  return (head == 0);

}
void list::add_first(int el)
{
    if (empty()) head = tail = new node(el);
    else
     head = new node(el);

}
void list::add_last(int el)
{
    if (empty()) head = tail = new node(el);
    else
     tail=tail->next = new node(el);

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you outputting anything at all ?

Comment: I am using the visual studio to output my code,but the main function is in a different file.

Comment: 1) a linked list is generally a *horribly inefficient* data structure on modern machines - prefer `std::vector` almost always. 2) why build your own? `std::list` and `std::forward_list` already exist. 3) there is such a thing as `std::sort` - you *could* use it.   Just guessing here for your specific use case, but I would *suspect* that just using a `std::vector` and `std::sort`ing it after each insertion, might actually turn out to be both simpler *and* faster.

Comment: I totally agree Jesper, the only reason I am using it is because teachers in my university are teaching us about linked list and they gave us tasks to solve them using only linked list .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done a small mistake in your `void list::add_first(int el)` method. As you did not add you all codes I have modified your code and which is available below. Please compare the below codes to understand you mistake, especially compare method `void list::add_first(int el)`  . Hope this will help.

struct node
        {
          public:
              int data;
              node *next;
              node(int val):data(val),next(NULL){}
        };

```
    class list
    {
      private:
         node *head,*tail, *temp;
      public:
         list();
         bool empty();
         void add_sorted(int el);
         void add_first(int el);
         void add_last(int el);
         void print();
    };

    list::list()
    {
      head = tail = 0;

    }
    void list::add_sorted(int el)
    {
       if (empty()) add_first(el);
       else if (el<=head->data) add_first(el);
       else if (el >= tail->data) add_last(el);
    }
    bool list::empty()
    {
      return (head == 0);

    }
    void list::add_first(int el)
    {
        if (empty()) head = tail = new node(el);
        else
        {
         //here temp is pointing to the first node of the list
         temp = head;
         head = new node(el); //now head is pointing to a new node
         head->next = temp; // and that new node is added to the list and finally head is pointing to the first node of the final list
        }

    }
    void list::add_last(int el)
    {
        if (empty()) head = tail = new node(el);//here I dont think this condition will ever satisfied
        else
         tail->next = new node(el);
         tail = tail->next;//more clearity

    }
    void list::print()
    {
      temp = head;
      while(temp)
      {
        std::cout<<temp->data<<", ";
        temp = temp->next;
      }
      std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
    int main()
    {
      list t1;
      t1.add_sorted(5);
      t1.add_sorted(3);
      t1.add_sorted(9);
      t1.print();
      return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of an insertion into a sorted linked list is to keep the list sorted.

This means that you will need to search the list to find an appropriate location to add the new element:

```
void addSorted(int value)
{
  node * new_element = new node(el);
  new_element->next = nullptr;
  if (head == nullptr)
  {
    head = new_element;
    tail = head;
  }
  else
  {
     node * p = head;
     node * previous = head;
     while (p != nullptr)
     {
       if (el > p.value)
       {
          new_element->next = p;
          previous->next = new_element;
          break;
       }
     }
     if (p == nullptr)
     {
        previous.next = new_element;
     }
  }
}
```

The idea here is that you need to search the list for the insertion point, then add your new element.  There are corner cases, such as when the `head` is null.

Comment: That's what I am trying to do ,but I wanted to compare integer (el) with head->data and tail->data before writing a for loop since head->data must contain the smallest integer and tail->data must contain the largest integer , if the el is bigger than tail->data then we add a node containing the element to last , and we do the opposite to head->data.